# Jquery mousewheel detect scroll position works not correctly

Tags: jquery, position, detect, mousewheel

Hi I do some js part on my website and have problem with mousewhell scroll.

This is my code how I detect scroll up or down.

```
$(window).on({
    'mousewheel': function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
});


$(window).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var delta = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -event.originalEvent.detail;

    if(delta > 0) {
        //up
    }else {
        //down
    }
});
```

I don't understand what is wrong. It works like random I scroll down it goes up or I scroll up it's go down or it's work normally. Can I detect position with other solution without plugin. It also work crazy when I scroll it with touchpad not mouse scroll

Thanks for you time

Comment: Can you create an example at jsfiddle.net? It would help.

Comment: O i forget it works crazy on macbook touchpad and magic mouse in windows it works great

Answer (score 2):

This answer might be interesting for horizontal scrolling

```
    $(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event)
    {
        var delta_one = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
        var delta_two = event.originalEvent.detail;
        var mydelta = delta_one || delta_two;
        var left = $('.yourDiv').scrollLeft();
        $('.yourDiv').scrollLeft(left + mydelta);    
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

that works: https://jsfiddle.net/fvd3jqdq/2/

```
$(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event)
{
    if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || event.originalEvent.detail < 0) {
        //UP
    }
    else{
        //DOWN
    }
});
```

Comment: O i forget it works crazy on macbook touchpad and magic mouse in windows it works great